# How to backup an Oracle database from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-12c

New to Oracle, usually work with SQL Server.

Is there an easy way to backup an Oracle database from SQL Developer.

I've read these links [Database Backup and Recovery User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmbckba.htm#BRADV8003) and [RMAN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/rman-overview-096633.html) and it's a CRAZY involved process!  There's gotta be an easier way, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. And then yes. Well, it depends.

What are your requirements?

### Backup / Restore Capabilities

Do you want a backup of the database ...

- ... for a restore
- ... to perform recovery
- ... to roll forward additional archive logs

Then RMAN is your tool of choice. Yes, RMAN is pretty complex and has a steep learning curve. However, once you have mastered it, you will benefit from a large variety of possibilities that RMAN provides you with, e.g. [central RMAN catalog](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/BRADV/managing-recovery-catalog.htm#BRADV8015) for multiple Oracle instances.

### Export / Import Capabilities

Do you want a dump of a database ....

- ... for a "restore" to a new server/instance
- ... no recovery required
- ... no additional roll forward of archive logs

...then you might want to consider using the EXPDP (see: [Data Pump Export](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SUTIL/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.htm#SUTIL200)) and IMPDP (see: [Data Pump Import](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SUTIL/datapump-import-utility.htm#SUTIL300)). These tools provide you with the ability to obtain schema-specific data and import the data into different tablespaces; or to filter the export via table names, dependencies. On import the schema can then be re-linked to a different schema (see: [REMAP_SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927)), etc.

### SQL Developer

SQL Developer has the capability to export data using a wizard. This is similar to the built-in EXPDP and IMPDP tools provided with the RDBMS installation. A quick guide to using the wizard can be found at: [Exporting and Importing Metadata and Data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#ADMQS256) and there in the section **Using SQL Developer for Exporting and Importing** (Tools | Database Export).

Comment: Thanks! Kinda suspected an answer like yours, as backups always depend on how you want to restore.